# Unselect all items in a listbox after initial load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a ListBox that initially displays with the first item selected.  I want it to display with no items selected.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please indicate if you are using WPF, Silverlight or WinForms

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
ListBox.ClearSelected()
```

or

```
ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Of course, they are member methods.

Comment: @Vladimir Does it work for a multi-value extended listbox as well? In my case this code doesn't work.

Comment: The first one worked a treat for my CheckedListBox. Thanks!

Comment: ListBox.ClearSelection();

Answer (score 3):

C# WPF (Clear Multiple)

Two more ways from code behind:

```
DemoListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
DemoListBox.UnselectAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
lb_MyListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: SelectedIndex = -1 will not work if you have a multi-edit listbox.

Comment: @kakridge precisely. I am facing the issue for mult-selct extend. What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

For clear multiple `ListBox`

```
foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
{
    ((ListBox)ctrl).SelectedIndex = -1;
    ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
}
```

Calling Method on button and from where you want to execute

```
ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
```

Answer (score 0):

ListItem.Selected is what drives this.  The default is false, which means the item will not be selected.  Your code has to be explicitly setting this to true for it to be displayed as selected.  You just need to remove the code that is doing that, which would look like `listItem.Selected = true;`. See [ListItem.Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx)