# Unselect listbox when other one is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two listboxes like this photo:

[image]

As you can see both sides are selected. I want to know how can I unselect one list when other one is clicked. Is that possible?

Comment: Add an event to the boxes that listens to when something is selected. Then call `OtherListBox.UnselectAll()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an event listener for a SelectedIndexChange on the respective list boxes, like below:

```
    // Have Box1 deselect any Box2 inputs on index change.
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBox2.ClearSelected();
    }

    // Have Box2 deselect any Box1 inputs on index change.
    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
    }
```

Additional resource to check out: [Unselect All Items in a Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070985/unselect-all-items-in-a-listbox)

Answer (score 1):

Following Code may help you for your problem but you ca also add clearSelected function on selectedIndexChanged event of function.

```
    namespace StackoverFlow4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Text = "UnSelected";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "Selected";
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = StackoverFlow4.Properties.Resources.tick;
            button1.Text = "Clear Selected";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.ClearSelected();
            listBox2.ClearSelected();
            button1.Text = "UnSelected";
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = StackoverFlow4.Properties.Resources.cross;
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = StackoverFlow4.Properties.Resources.cross;
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = StackoverFlow4.Properties.Resources.tick;
            button1.Text = "Clear Selected";
        }
    }
}
```

firstly both are unselected
[image]
clear list if one to be selected
[image]
clear both if both are selected
[image]

I'm too new here sorry for bads and Goods
Stay blessed